# What is Object k?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (table == EMPTY_TABLE) {
        inflateTable(threshold);
    }
    if (key == null)
        return putForNullKey(value);
    int hash = hash(key);
    int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
            V oldValue = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            e.recordAccess(this);
            return oldValue;
        }
    }

    modCount++;
    addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
    return null;
}
```

I am trying to understand the HashMap implemintation. I understood everything except this line - Object k;
Please, explain how this Object k appears??

Comment: I dont understand your confusion. It appears because someone declared it there. What doesn't make sense?

Comment: `Object k` is not related to the genric type `K key`. It could be named `Object foo` and the code would still do the exact same thing

Comment: k is used here: (k = e.key) == key. Appears to be some sort of boxing to make check if the objects are reference equal (in case your 'K' (type of your Key) is a primitive type, it would box it and would return false since they wouldn't be reference equal but if they were both non primitive types, it would check if both objects are the same reference. Since you have the key.equals(k) equality check later, this is just a performance check to make sure you don't call the potentially expensive .equals() method if your keys are the same object.

Comment: Thank's for answers, i understood. I have not noticed - k = e.key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that implementation of a `HashMap`, the data structure was backed by an array of linked lists of entries. These entries have a key and a value.

That variable `k` is used to store the key for each entry while iterating over the linked list bucket. If it's found to be equal (reference and then value equality) to the key with which you're trying to insert a value, then that value replaces the old.